# Error When Calling Exit Function | Recursive

Tags: excel, vba

I was playing around with recursive and create this.

ABBB runs OK, get true

BABB runs OK, get true

BBAB runs OK, get true

BBBA does not run properly, get false

This part of the function runs properly, but when exit function is called the line jumps to the last end if line of the code. When I f8 through the code it jumps back and forth three times. It is almost as if it is compiling x3 the if loop instead of exiting the function.

OK this works. Thank you all.

```
Function practieRecursive(userstring, UserStringIndex) As Boolean
    UserStringIndex = UserStringIndex + 1
    If CInt(UserStringIndex) > Len(userstring) Then
        practieRecursive = False
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Mid(userstring, UserStringIndex, 1) = "A" Then
        practieRecursive = True
        Debug.Print practieRecursive
        Exit Function
    Else
        practieRecursive = practieRecursive(userstring, UserStringIndex)
        Exit Function
    End If
    Debug.Print practieRecursive
End Function
```

Comment: Bring up the *Call Stack* debugger toolwindow. You'll see that `Exit Function` only pops the top-most stack frame - you need to exit every stack frame that was pushed - the behavior is completely normal AFAICT. What's the error?

Comment: you are right, will work with this tonight. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting `Mid(userstring, UserStringIndex, 1) = "A"` before checking `CInt(UserStringIndex) = Len(userstring)`. Reorder your checks.

```
Function practieRecursive(userstring, UserStringIndex) As Boolean
    UserStringIndex = UserStringIndex + 1
    If CInt(UserStringIndex) = Len(userstring) Then
        practieRecursive = False
        Exit Function
    elseIf Mid(userstring, UserStringIndex, 1) = "A" Then
Stop
        practieRecursive = True
        Exit Function
    Else
        Call practieRecursive(userstring, UserStringIndex)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: have to swap from = to a > or else lose last char. this works better though, much cleaner. still having problem, see text in OP

Comment: Good catch on `>` vs `=` ! I'll have another look at the op.

Comment: i caught it when looking at my original code which is what gave you the error LOL and re another look